# What does the acronym EMSAH spell out in Mort(e)?

Tags: morte

In the novel [Mort(e)](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22181034-mort-e), much of the plot centers around an ambiguously defined virus or disease, EMSAH.  One conversation refers to it as an acronym:

> "The Colony told you that EMSAH is an acronym, right?" she asked.
>
> "That's right."
>
> "Do you know what it means?"
>
> "I may have briefly," Mort(e) said.
>
> "It's a corruption of the word *messiah*, first spoken by an animal
>   who was learning how to read."

Is there an actual acronym decode for EMSAH in the novel?  Or is it simply a corrupted word that is *referred to* (incorrectly) as an acronym?

Comment: I've changed the link to one that isn't behind a paywall

Comment: @Valorum I went through about 10 links looking for one that wasn't a) clearly commercial, b) cluttered with ad crap, or c) obviously a paywall.  I didn't realize Globe was paywall, sorry :0

Comment: Goodreads is commercial, but it's still a pretty open resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked my good friend Robert Repino this question. In short,  it's not an acronym at all.

> **Q.** *Is EMSAH an acronym for something (e.g. as well as a corruption of Messiah)?*
>
> **Robert Repino:** *Not an acronym--just a corruption of messiah.*
>
> <sub>[Via Twitter](https://www.twitter.com/Answerguesser40/status/1013818472609075201)</sub>